# <style> tag in header.php in WordPress not working in IE 8

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

I have following code in header.php file on a WP theme :

```
<style type="text/css">
  #Subheader{display:none;}
</style>
```

This code hides a div with id="Subheader" which works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE 8. When I look at source code in IE, the code is there, but its not hiding the div.

Also I have similar code :

```
<style type="text/css">
#Footer, .lwa-submit-links {display:none;}
</style>
```

in a page from wp-admin page editor, which should hide the footer div when that page is opened. Again its not working in IE.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your HTML validates and you have a proper doctype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds exceedingly like a long standing bug in IE, whereby trying to hide an element using display:none didn't work if it's parent container was already display none. When the parent was re-shown, the child also became visible even though it was still display:none.

The problem is described and demoed in an interesting site: Position is Everything, about browser bugs. The full link for this problem is http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/ienondisappearcontentbugPIE/index.htm.

However it was apparently a thing which affects IE in Compatibility mode (set from Tools/Compatibility settings); I don't know if you happen to be running in that mode? Even if not it might be well worth while playing around with the sequence you set things to display none to see if that will fix your problem.